# Construct a Binary Search Tree using the following keys: Try, throw, catch, cin, cout, static, friend

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I was given an assignment question to do and I was racking my head for a long time trying to write a code for this question. It will be really helpful if anyone can help me in finishing this question.

I am a complete noobie in C++. I went through many resources but failed to finish this.

Here is the code I came up with so far. Is this how it should be done?

Edit:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class BST {
    
    struct node {
        string data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;

    node* insert(string x, node* t)
    {
        if(t == NULL)
        {
            t = new node;
            t->data = x;
            t->left = t->right = NULL;
        }
        else if(x < t->data)
            t->left = insert(x, t->left);
        else if(x > t->data)
            t->right = insert(x, t->right);
        return t;
    }

    
    void inorder(node* t) {
        if(t == NULL)
            return;
        inorder(t->left);
        cout << t->data << " ";
        inorder(t->right);
    }

public:
    BST() {
        root = NULL;
    }

    void insert(string x) {
        root = insert(x, root);
    }

    void display() {
        inorder(root);
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    BST t;
    t.insert("Try");
    t.insert("throw");
    t.insert("catch");
    t.insert("cin");
    t.insert("cout");
    t.insert("static");
    t.insert("friend");
    t.display();
    return 0; 
}
```

I got an output like this

> Try catch cin cout friend static throw

Comment: Please post, in text form, the code you've written so far or a [mcve].

Comment: I recommend using a node that has `std::string` for the data or key field.  The words `Try, throw, catch, cin, cout, static, friend` are all strings.

Comment: What part of creating a Binary Search Tree are you having issues with?

Comment: Hint: `struct Node {std::string data; Node * p_left_subtree; Node * p_right_subtree;};`

Comment: So instead of having int values in node, I have to take string in nodes right and just display the output after creating

Comment: If you convert your keywords into integers, you can keep your `int` data field.  Like maybe have a relationship like `<try, 1>`, `<throw, 2>`, etc.